# Natural Deduction proof - Is it correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Let me know if this proof is correct. This is in french.

Translation French --> English

**prémisse = premise**

**supposition = assumption**

[image: Fitch Proof]

I now know that this is 100% incorrect. Does anyone know how to resolve it mathematically?

.

Edit 1 : Thanks to @Mauro Curto here is what I came up with

[image: Fitch proof]

Comment: **This is a Fitch-based proof in a Hilbert Deductive system

Comment: Much better ... Put step 6 inside the subproof before line 5 ... and think about where it comes from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

> [image: no]

Not quite.

Conditional Introduction deduces a conditional statement whose antecedent is the assumption of a subproof and whose consequent is the conclusion.  Thus when you assume $p$ with the aim of deriving $r$, you are intending to introduce $p\to r$ outside the context of that subproof.

Conversely, Conditional Elimination requires a conditional statement and its antecedent to both be accessible in the context where you intend to derive the consequent.  Thus all such eliminations using the assumed conditionals of $p\to \textsf{whatever}$ must take place inside a context where $p$ is available.

That is in the innermost nest of the suproofs, which derives $q$ and $q\to r$, and from these another Conditional Elimination derives $r$.  And so...

$$\fitch{~~1.~p\to(q\to r)}{\fitch{~~2.~p\to q}{\fitch{~~3.~p}{~~4.~q\\~~5.~q\to r\\~~6.~r}\\~~7.~p\to r}\\~~8.~(p\to q)\to(p\to r)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your derivation is incorrect. Your supposition in step 2 is not the adequate supposition. After you colse a supposition you can't use the supposition anymore so your step 7 is wrong, nad therefore the step 8 is also wrong.

Since the main connective of the consequent is a conditional you have to use the "practical rule" of the introduction of the conditional wich states that you have to assume the antecedent and then try to derivate the consequent. You have to use this practical rule twice in this derivation.

A derivations looks like:

$1). p → (q → r) - premise$

$2). p → q - supposition$

$3). p - supposition$

$4)....$

So now you close supposition 3 after you derivate $r$, and then you close supposition 2 after you derivate $p → r$

Comment: Feedback is useful. I'm having this course in french so it's hard to translate everything you say. Could mathematically show me the how you would use the introduction of the conditional to derivate the consequent twice. Sorry I know I'm asking a lot. I been on this for about 3-4 hours

Comment: huge thanks again. I'll read about this again in the book and with the info you provided I'll be able to make more like these in the future. I'll let you know what i came up with

Comment: Hey, I edited my post with my new answer. Let me know if I got it right this time :)

Comment: You are close, but step 5 is incorrect because you can't get (r) from (p → (q → r)) and (q) by E→. In order to get (r) you need (q → r) and (q) so that way you can use E→. Remember to specify where did you close assumptions. I don't particularly know fitch natural deduction system but I suggest you that you don't use SH like in step 7: the 
virtuosity of natural deduction is that we specify step by step the derivation and SH (although it's fine) it is a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

No, not correct.

Line 5 cannot refer to line 3, since that is part of a subproof that was closed right after line 3

Line 6, 7, and 8 are all not correct: you introduce a conditional by *closing* a subproof, inferring a conditional with as its antecednt the assumption of that subproof, and as its conseuqent the last line of that subproof (or at the very least, a line contained within that subproof). On lines 6 and 7 you are not closing any subproofs, and line 8 is not referring to the assumption of the subproof you just closed

To be harsh this but frank: it's a mess!  Please study the rule for conditional introduction more carefully ... not just syntactically, but also conceptually and indeed purely logically. Nothing you do here makes any logical sense if you step back from the strings of symbols and think about what you do here.

Comment: Can you point me towards where I should start with this proof ? I tried to use LEM but as you can see it doesn't work out.  Let me know :(

Comment: @nico Yes. First you should stop treating this like some kind of game of putting the symbols in some kind of right order. Instead, try to understand what actual proof techniques the rules are formalizing. In this case, it's all about conditional proofs. Presumably (hopefully!) your book will have a discussion on conditional proofs with some examples. And some examples that are not completely formal, but that you can actually understand and follow as logical reasoning. It is only when you grasp what the rules are trying to formalize that you will be able to do formal proofs.

Comment: You sound really harsh for some reason. Please don't comment like that unless you really want to help. Some people are new at this and really need the help. But still thank you for your time it was still appreciated.

Comment: @nico My apologies if I come over really harsh!  I genuinely want to help!  And the first step is exactly what I said: first you need to understand how proofs work at a much more informal level before you try and formalize them. And yes, if I sound harsh it is because I have tried to help too many people who don't follow that advice and merely focus on the formal proof, and it always turns out to be a disaster.Trust me: you are never going to get good at these proofs if you don't first understand the rules conceptually.

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you for saying that.